# Set / Get JSessionID - Proxy blocks set-cookies attribute

Tags: angular, proxy, angular5, session-bean

I got a problem using the Angular-Proxy to get/set the JSessionID for a @SessionBean. (What is usually handled by the Browser?)
I´m trying to send the Request from localhost:4200 to localhost:8080. To overcome the CORS-Problem, I use a Proxy (proxy.conf.json) like that:

```
{
  "/test/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080/",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/test/": ""
    },
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Now I was trying to use the HttpInterceptor to intercept the request and the response to read the set-cookie header and set it in the following request. 
The problem here is, that (at least i think so) the proxy kind of filters the set-cookie header so the intercepted response is without the set-cookie attribute with the jsessionid.

[image]
[image]
When I try this with Postman, everything works fine :/ 
Any Idea to change the proxy setting to allow the headers, so I can set the JSessionId in the Interceptor 
OR 
Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kicked the anuzlar Proxy conf and manually allowed in my Backend-HttpFilter that my localhost:4200 can access the backend. Therefore the Session-Cookie could be set properly and i havn´t had to manipulate it in frontend.

Not a satisfaction but it worked.

Comment: is this still works fine for u ?